# Can't edit a service file in system directory - Read-only file system

Tags: linux, file-permissions, coreos

I want to edit a service file located in `/usr/lib/systemd/system`. Even if I edit it as root (sudo), it says `Can't open file for writing`.

I thought it's a permission problem, but when trying to add rights to the file I get: `chmod: changing permissions of 'flannel-docker-opts.service': Read-only file system`.

Since that isn't media(USB or something), I don't think I should mount it?

I'm on coreOS btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was more specific to Container Linux (specifically coreOS).

There are two methods of overriding default container Linux settings:

1. Copying the unit file from /usr/lib64/systemd/system to /etc/systemd/system and modifying the chosen settings
2. Using systemd drop-in units

I've used the latter.

I was configuring a file `flannel-docker-opts.service` located in the system direcotry. I solved it using a system drop-in. First step was creating a directory `flannel-docker-opts.service.d` in `/etc/systemd/system`. I created a configuration file in that directory, with my changes.

More info in the official coreOS [documentation](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-systemd-drop-in-units.html)

Answer (score 0):

If a filesystem has been mounted read-only, chmod will not work since it's a write operation too.

Try remounting it read-write:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw '/usr/lib/systemd/system/yourfile'
```

Comment: I get `mount: /usr/lib64/systemd/system/flannel-docker-opts.service not mounted or bad option`